# CakePHP 3 : link to any action in PagesController opens same action

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.0

I have to link to different actions in `PagesController`.

I have created many static pages and for that I have defined an action like

```
public function contact(){

}
```

now when I access `www.mysite.com/pages/contact` instead of opening `contact.ctp` it opens the default `display` action.

The `routes.php` file contains

```
Router::defaultRouteClass('DashedRoute');

Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {

    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);

    $routes->connect('/pages/*', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display']);

    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});

Plugin::routes();
```

How can I access the static pages or other `actions` of `PagesController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$routes->connect('/pages/:action/*', ['controller' => 'Pages']);
```

Now you can call to diferent actions. e.g.

www.mysite.com/pages/contact

www.mysite.com/pages/about

www.mysite.com/pages/someaction

Comment: if you need to define actions for your static pages, they are not static.

Comment: @AlexStallen you are right, I use this solution for statcs pages who contain is saved in data base and can be modified via admin panel.

Comment: Why not use a normal Controller then?

Answer (score 1):

The default routing for the `PagesController` is to direct everything to the `display` action.

In order to add additional actions, you would need to route these specifically.

```
$routes->connect('/pages/contact', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'contact']);
```

Or, alternatively, if you do not want everything to go through the `display` action, remove the specific line in `routes.php` that directs everything there. CakePHP would auto-route anything beginning with `/pages/` to the PagesController, and anything after the slash to it's appropriate action.

Comment: Thanks Warren, +1 for your answer. Although this could be a good answer but I don't want to delete the whole line because in future I might need it.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the view file src/Template/Pages/contact.ctp you can access it using the URL http://example.com/pages/contact

No need to change anythin in routes.php they are fine. No need to create a method in your PagesController, this is a simple and optional controller for serving up static content.